# Statistical test to determine which system more accurately describes a trend

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have a known variable, for example a trend of heart rate, and two systems (A, & B) who sample this variable the same number of times but at different, unequal intervals.

For example, system A simply samples once every 60s and system B tries to predict when changes occur and samples then.

What are some suitable methods to determine which system more accurately describes the underlying trend?

One definition might be which system better "captures the variance" of the underlying trend. In this case could I perform bootstrapped measurements, say with a starting offset each time, and compare the standard deviations of system A vs B and using an unpaired t-test?

Looking forward to hearing your opinions.

Thanks

Comment: It vaguely bothers me that you want to know "which system more accurately describes the underlying trend" without actually knowing what the underlying trend is. However, with heart rate, max and min values might be more useful, so you'd use the system that gives higher maxs and lower mins.

Comment: @barrycarter The underlying trend is in fact known. I'm trying to understand sensible ways of determining which system captures a better "picture" of the overall trend. Thanks

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you use a simple squares-of-differences technique to see how each varies from the true underlying value?

Comment: Each system simply samples the true value at a given time (different for each system) so there is never any "error" as such. I am trying to find a method of analysis that will tell me which system captures more of the changes in the trend (eg. highs and lows)

Comment: For example, system A simply samples once every 60s and system B tries to predict when changes occur and samples then. What analysis will tell me if system B is performing significantly better than A.

Comment: If you're most interested in the highs and lows, I'd suggest comparing the extreme values of the actual data to the extreme values of the two systems?

Comment: Either the highs & lows, or just overall variance I guess. What I'm asking is how best to compare these properties? Thanks again.